# Pandas Df.head() does not display when called inside the method()?

Tags: pandas, sklearn-pandas

Cannot access the pandas dataframe.head() or dataframe.describe() when the call is made inside a method.
    def develop_df():

```
    studentData = { 
    0 : {
        'name' : 'Aadi',
        'age' : 16,
        'city' : 'New york'
        },
    1 : {
        'name' : 'Jack',
        'age' : 34,
        'city' : 'Sydney'
        },
    }

    print("Now lets print student data")
    print(studentData)
    print("%" * 80)
    print("Create a df and then print head")
    st_df = pd.DataFrame(studentData)
    st_df.head()
    print("%" * 80)
develop_df()
```

Output:

```
Now lets print student data 
{0: {'name': 'Aadi', 'age': 16, 'city': 'New york'}, 1: {'name': 'Jack', 'age': 34, 'city': 'Sydney'}}
Create a df and then print head
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

But, as seen when called outside the method, it works.

```
studentData = { 
0 : {
    'name' : 'Aadi',
    'age' : 16,
    'city' : 'New york'
},
1 : {
    'name' : 'Jack',
    'age' : 34,
    'city' : 'Sydney'
},
 }
print("Now lets print student data")
print(studentData)
print("%" * 80)
print("Create a df and then print head")
st_df = pd.DataFrame(studentData)
st_df.head()
```

Output:
    Now lets print student data
    {0: {'name': 'Aadi', 'age': 16, 'city': 'New york'}, 1: {'name': 'Jack', 'age': 34, 'city': 'Sydney'}}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    Create a df and then print head
              0         1
    age      16          34
    city    New york    Sydney
    name    Aadi        Jack

Any suggestion on resolving it?

Comment: try `print(st_df.head())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pretty-print within a loop, first import the `display_html` function:

```
from IPython.display import display_html
```

Then wrap `display_html` around any calls to `df.head()` within a function definition, for example:

```
display_html(st_df.head())
```